# Rails - why I'm getting undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm displaying question by categories and each question has its own number. I made it like this(index.html.erb):

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
     <div id=<%= "box#{category.id}" -%>>
        <h1><%= category.name %></h1>
        <% category.questions.each_with_index do |question, i| %>
            <ul class="question-list" style="display: inline;">
                <li><%= link_to (i + 1), show_path %></li>
            </ul>
        <% end %>
     </div>
<% end %>
```

And when I click on question number I would like to show it like this(show.html.erb):

```
<div class="question-wrapper">
       <h1><%= @category.name %></h1>
       <div class="image left-align">
         <%= question_image_tag(question, :large) %>
       </div>
       <div class="question-text right-align">
        <%= @question.question_name %>
       </div>
       <p><%= @question.answer %></p>
 </div>
```

This is my controller:

```
def index
    @categories = Category.all
    @questions = Question.all
end

def show
    @categories = Category.all
    @questions = Question.all
end
```

Now, I'm getting undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass (also throws error for all methods in show.html.erb)  and I can't resolve it.

**Question: What should I do to resolve undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass?**

Update: 
- stack trace

> NoMethodError - undefined method `category' for nil:NilClass:
>   app/controllers/quizz_controller.rb:13:in`show'

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    mount Attachinary::Engine => "/attachinary"
    root to: "quizz#home"
    %w(quizz
       show).each do |page|
       get page, to: "quizz##{page}", as: page
    end
    resources :categories
    resources questions
end
```

Comment: In `show.html.erb`, you have used `@category` and `@question` - from where you are getting these instance variables ?

Comment: From models. I have two models, category and question!

Comment: But on your show controller action you define `@categories` and `@questions` you don't define either of the variables @dkp mentions.  Hence your issue

Comment: @Unknown19 you have to define the instance variables in your controller in order to access them in views. If you are not able to get it, then please post your association between models, result of `rake routes`.

Comment: @dkp association is that category has_many :questions, question belongs_to :category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pass the *question id* with the *params* and find the *@question* from the question id in *show action* of your controller.

Your respective views and controller code should look as follows:

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
 <div id=<%= "box#{category.id}" -%>>
    <h1><%= category.name %></h1>
    <% category.questions.each_with_index do |question, i| %>
        <ul class="question-list" style="display: inline;">
            <li><%= link_to (i + 1), show_path(question_id: question.id) %></li>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

**Controller**

```
def show
  @question = Question.find_by_id(params[:question_id])
  @category = @question.category
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<div class="question-wrapper">
   <h1><%= @category.name %></h1>
   <div class="image left-align">
     <%= question_image_tag(question, :large) %>
   </div>
   <div class="question-text right-align">
    <%= @question.question_name %>
   </div>
   <p><%= @question.answer %></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Something is wrong. Now I'm getting undefined method `category' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @Unknown19 thats because `@question is nil`. please post stack trace and also add your `routes.rb` to question.

Comment: You are using `quizz_controller` ?

Comment: @Unknown19: the problem is in your routes, write the correct path for the show action as per the controller

Comment: @dpk yes, I am using quizz_controller. I'm displaying quizz game in it.

Comment: @Unknown19 Updated the answer, please give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

You are kidding with the code.

```
def index
    @categories = Category.all
    @questions = Question.all
end

def show
    @category = Category.find(id-of-category)
    @question = Question.find(id-of-question)
end
```

When you are calling index method that means you need all the questions and categories to show to user.

But when you need to show a particular question or show method that means you need to find that particular question and category.

Inside your show.html.erb you have used the instance variable like @category and @question, Can you tell me where you have defined the same to use on the view.

@Unknown19 user, I want to suggest you one think that is, You just read about the Scaffold and try to implement a single model with Scaffold I am sure you will learn many things and How you should write the methods and their instance, It's the best way for you to learn the Restful mechanism.

Comment: I don't think I understand you. I didn't define them. 
Also I tried to find by id but not working. I still don't know what I messed up?!

Comment: That's why suggest you try with scaffold, you will easily get that what you have messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Just send category_id and question_id when you click question number and change code of show method to

```
def show 
  @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
end
```

and change index.html.erb form

```
<li><%= link_to (i + 1), show_path %></li>
```

to

```
<li><%= link_to (i + 1), show_path(category_id: category.id, question_id: question.id) %></li>
```

Comment: Why every time you are coping the answers of other developer ?

Comment: @Bharatsoni its not copied I am little late

Comment: And I am suggesting my way to resolve error not copied your answer

Comment: @Ansar Just did like you say but still getting the same error?

Comment: and why i will copy answer of any developer this is a very silly question any rails developer can answer of this

Comment: Your answers are always slimier with one who has given first answer. We are only telling you silly mistake but you are doing this, It's not first time, I have realize that from past few days.

Comment: check rails console and see what you get with params, if you are on show page and  params have category_id and question_id then you will not see any error

Comment: Anyway go ahead I just tell you nothing else.

Comment: @Ansar, like you say..I'm in show page, but in console I have no errors. It shows me category and question id

Comment: @Bharatsoni sorry dear, I am not copied  any developer answers but some time simple question have similar solutions what can I do about that, I will see if it hurts you I will not answer any question if you are there, fine ;)

Comment: No problem brother, Just wants to confirm with you nothing else and doesn't   hurt me at all.

Comment: here it is: 
`[26/Apr/2016:13:07:07 +0200] "GET /show?category_id=3&question_id=13 HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0.0595
 [26/Apr/2016:13:07:07 +0200] "GET /show?category_id=3&question_id=13 HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0.0598
[26/Apr/2016:13:07:08 +0200] "POST /__better_errors/c7584e617f497f89/variables HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0671`

Comment: @Unknown19 Please check any same spelling of objects on show method and  view

Answer (score 0):

Pass category id & question id in params  like below:

```
<li><%= link_to (i + 1), question(category_id: category.id, question_id: question.id) %></li>
```

Write the below in your controller:

```
def show 
  @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
end
```